# how to get inode from android <19

Tags: android, runtime.exec, inode

trying to get the inode for a file, tried following code it works for api >=19 (actually api>21 android has Os to get inode info), but on api <=18 the command "ls -il" does not return anything.

also tried "/system/bin/ls -il", it does not return either.

the ls -il returns "114993 -rw-rw---- u0_a59   u0_a59    9801728 2017-02-08 13:08 thefileName.ext" on api >=19.

not sure if this is reliable way to get the inode info.

```
public static String getIndoeFromPath(String path){
    String inode = "";
    String cmd = ("ls -il " + path);

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();            
        process.waitFor();

        String ret = output.toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "getIndoeFromPath(), output.toString():"+
 output.toString()+", ret = output.toString();:"+ret); /<=== it has empty in the string

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ret)) {
            ret = ret.trim();
            String[] splitArr = ret.split("\\s+");
            if (splitArr.length>0) {
                inode = splitArr[0];
            }
        }            
    } catch(Exception e) {} 
    finally {
       if (reader != null) {
           try {
               reader.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {}
       }
    }
    return inode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `stat` command

```
'stat README.txt
File: README.txt
Size: 480      Blocks: 8       IO Blocks: 512 regular file
Device: fd09h/64777d     Inode: 269424   Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)       Uid: ( 2000/   shell)   Gid: ( 2000/   shell)
Access: 2017-11-01 12:55:56.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2017-11-01 12:55:56.000000000 +0200
Change: 2021-01-17 15:55:19.367560281 +0200'
```